# Angular ngOnInit not working on route share component

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a component "MenuComponent" that loads a menu when a link is clicked in the sidebar. The "MenuComponent" is child of a "MenusComponent" through `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` When I click on the menu in the sidebar the link changes to one of the following.

```
#/cms/menus/1/menus/1
#/cms/menus/1/menus/3
#/cms/menus/1/menus/5
#/cms/menus/1/menus/6
```

I would like to load the menu and setup some properties whenever the link is clicked. I do this in;

```
  ngOnInit() {
      let menuid = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
      this.LocalService.PlacementMenus.Activate(menuid);
    this.Initialise();
    this.LocalService.changeMenuComponents('menuList');
      let placementid = this.route.snapshot.params.placementid;
      this.LocalService.AllPlacements.Activate(placementid);
  }
```

But ngOnInit does not work the second time I click a menu in the sidebar. i see there are other hooks such as;

```
ngAfterContentInit()
ngAfterViewInit()
```

But none of these work.

Comment: If the sidebar component containing the links is outside router-outlet it will not reload on navigation, if for some reason you really need the sidebar to regenerate each time, you need to place it inside the outlet. That being said, observing route changes as described in the answer would be much more efficient.

Comment: I don't want the sidebar to reload. I want the component to be regenerated

Answer (score 0):

The snapshot is just that, a snapshot at a particular point in time:

```
this.route.snapshot.params.id;
```

Use the observable instead. Then it will update each time the parameters change.

```
    this.route.params.subscribe(
     params => {
        let menuid = +params['id'];
        // OR let menuid = +paramMap.get('id');
        this.LocalService.PlacementMenus.Activate(menuid);
        this.Initialise();
        this.LocalService.changeMenuComponents('menuList');
        let placementid = this.route.snapshot.params.placementid;
        this.LocalService.AllPlacements.Activate(placementid);
     }
  );
```

For a little cleaner code, you could add all of the above method calls into one method and call that from inside the subscribe.

Comment: But why doesn't the component itself reload? I want the component to reload each time the link is clicked as if it was a new component.

Comment: You solution seems to work. Maybe I don't understand how ngOnInit works. Is there a way to reload the entire component each time the link is clicked?

Comment: No. ngOnInit only executes one time ... When the component is first created. But you can watch for parameter changes using the technique shown above.